# Excel VBA: saving partial data creates new row each time. How to update if row has values

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a simple form that allows to enter counts at different times of the day.

My form loads the values of the last row in the table to the UserForm so that whoever opens the form to enter the next count gets the previous values placed in the form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim lr As Long
lr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
eightWkd.Value = Cells(lr, 3)
nineWkd.Value = Cells(lr, 4)
ten30Wkd.Value = Cells(lr, 6)
noonWkd.Value = Cells(lr, 8)
one30Wkd.Value = Cells(lr, 10)
threeWkd.Value = Cells(lr, 12)
four30Wkd.Value = Cells(lr, 14)
sixWkd.Value = Cells(lr, 15)
```

But, each submission creates a new row. 
[image: screenshot of excel sheet]

Here is my code for my submit button, setting the values. Changing the loaded values works. I find the first empty row

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("daily_count")
Dim lr As Long, varDay As Long
With ws
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, varDay).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    .Cells(lr, 1).Value = Me.DateWkd.Value
    .Cells(lr, 2).Value = Me.DayWkd.Value
    .Cells(lr, 3).Value = Me.eightWkd.Value
    .Cells(lr, 4).Value = Me.nineWkd.Value
    .Cells(lr, 6).Value = Me.ten30Wkd.Value
    .Cells(lr, 8).Value = Me.noonWkd.Value
    .Cells(lr, 10).Value = Me.one30Wkd.Value
    .Cells(lr, 12).Value = Me.threeWkd.Value
    .Cells(lr, 14).Value = Me.four30Wkd.Value
    .Cells(lr, 15).Value = Me.sixWkd.Value
```

I tried the following logic, to choose between the last existing row, and a new row, based on whether the date value (column A) is set, but it didn't work.

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy") Then
r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Else
r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, varDay).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End If
```

So, how do I update cells in the row instead of creating a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the .Find method to find the row with the current date and then update the values of that row if found, and if not found then add the values to the next free row:

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("daily_count")
Dim lr As Long, varDay As Long, rng as Range
FindVal = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")
Set Rng = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=FindVal, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    With ws
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 1).Value = Me.DateWkd.Value
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 2).Value = Me.DayWkd.Value
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 3).Value = .Cells(Rng.Row, 3).Value + Me.eightWkd.Value
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 4).Value = .Cells(Rng.Row, 4).Value + Me.nineWkd.Value
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 6).Value = .Cells(Rng.Row, 6).Value + Me.ten30Wkd.Value
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 8).Value = .Cells(Rng.Row, 8).Value + Me.noonWkd.Value
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 10).Value = .Cells(Rng.Row, 10).Value + Me.one30Wkd.Value
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 12).Value = .Cells(Rng.Row, 12).Value + Me.threeWkd.Value
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 14).Value = .Cells(Rng.Row, 14).Value + Me.four30Wkd.Value
        .Cells(Rng.Row, 15).Value = .Cells(Rng.Row, 15).Value + Me.sixWkd.Value
    End With
Else
    With ws
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, varDay).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        .Cells(lr, 1).Value = Me.DateWkd.Value
        .Cells(lr, 2).Value = Me.DayWkd.Value
        .Cells(lr, 3).Value = Me.eightWkd.Value
        .Cells(lr, 4).Value = Me.nineWkd.Value
        .Cells(lr, 6).Value = Me.ten30Wkd.Value
        .Cells(lr, 8).Value = Me.noonWkd.Value
        .Cells(lr, 10).Value = Me.one30Wkd.Value
        .Cells(lr, 12).Value = Me.threeWkd.Value
        .Cells(lr, 14).Value = Me.four30Wkd.Value
        .Cells(lr, 15).Value = Me.sixWkd.Value
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm seeing the same behavior. I changed the "find" to look for the day of the week, and I am getting a "type mismatch" error on ".Cells(rng.Row, 1).Value = .Cells(rng.Row, 1).Value + Me.DateWkd.Value"

Comment: Ok, I got this to work. I stripped the second ".Cells(Rng.Row, #) +" out of the first group of lines which cleared the error. Thanks